# preg_match pattern in div

Tags: php, regex

```
<div class="large-notice"><h2>yyyy</h2><p>ABCD</p><form>zzzz</form></div>
```

Using this `preg_match`, I’m able to extract all the text between `<div>....</div>`:

```
preg_match('#<div class="large-notice">(.*?)</div>#s', $one, $n);
```

But I want only the text between `<p>` and `</p>`, i.e. `ABCD`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a variety of ways to do this, and a lot depends on whether we're dealing with only this one specific piece of markup or an entire document that has some fluctuation.

Anyway, either of the following should work:

```
preg_match('#<div class="large-notice"><h2>.*?</h2><p>(.*?)</p><form>.*?</form></div>#s', $one, $n);

preg_match('#<p>(.*?)</p>#s', $one, $n);
```

Answer (score 0):

the answer earlier is better in my opinion but you can also use strpos to find the staring and ending position of the string you're looking for and substr it...
cheers